# How do I fix this error in cpp vs code Mac?

Tags: c++, error-handling

I have been trying to fix this error for days now. Every time I try to run code in cpp on Mac I get this error message

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm thinking it has something to do with either the linker or the clang file, let me know what I need to do to fix this

-- I just fixed this, it was a problem with my settings, thank you.

Comment: Implement an `int main()`. Also remember that in VSCode the default behavior is to build only the active file into your executable. If you have more than 1 source file you need to follow the  instructions in the VSCode documentation on how to have it compile all of your files in the same folder. Or you need to switch to use CMake or a Makefile as your build task.

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x = 9;
    cout << x;
    return 0;
}I have already implemented an int main(), I have only been compiling simple cout codes and it keeps giving the same error code

Comment: have you saved your file before compiling? How are you compiling your code? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69089995/edit) any clarifications into your question

Comment: Look at the compile commands in the terminal. Verify that the correct file is used. Also use some other editor to verify that the file contains the contents that you expect. I also suspect that you didn't save your file before compiling.